Macro Issue in Umbraco 9.3.1: Can't Edit After Update
In Umbraco 9.3.1, I have an RTE field. When I try to insert a PDF using the "Insert Macro" option, the fields are displayed, and I upload the PDF. After that, when I try to edit the macro, clicking the macro causes it to close instead of opening. How can I fix this? I also tried this in Umbraco 10.8.6, and the same issue occurs.
